# Is there an online tool that grabs XML from some remote URL then provides a way to get the data via json using javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, json

Its easy to grab XML directly of your own domain from some local URL, but cross-domain isn't. How would you grab the XML data that is found at http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=keep+skat with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! I would use [YQL (Yahoo Query Language)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) and its pretty simple. You can definitely convert from XML to JSON and also can pass **callback function** to use along with `JSONP`.

Please visit [YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console) and you can build your query from there.

For your problem, use this REST call (which I used to generate from YQL console):

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2Fcomplete%2Fsearch%3Foutput%3Dtoolbar%26q%3Dkeep%2Bskat%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=myCallbackFunc
```

Response from this URL will give you the JSON from the XML returned from your URL.

Comment: THanks! That's a little too high of a learning curve for tonight. I'll have to get back to this later!... Are there any other services? Also is it possible to retrive that XML and a string wrapped in json with YQL?

Comment: You mean that you want a JSON and as a node in JSON you want the XML itself to be there?

Comment: yeah, exactly! I know it might seem to defeat the awesomeness of json, but I'd like that for certain situations where I don't have access to the main code and they need me to manipulate XML and send it back. Can you make such a sample where YQL grabs the XML from that sample link and stores it as a string in the JSON?